# Why Apache IoTDB cannot be restarted and return normal when replicating the same data files?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

I restarted the Apache IoTDB server, but then it couldn't be started again. I checked the log record, and find that there's warning in the configuration node part. The warning information is the datanode failed to start. After renaming the original data and replicate them to the server, the service can start normally. Anyone know why this error occurs?